# Elastic Beanstalk Worker Tier returning 400s

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a basic spring application with the following endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class WorkerController {

    @Autowired    
    private WorkerService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void receive(@RequestBody Long id) {
        service.receive(id);
    }
}
```

In another application, JMS (specifically Amazon's SQS implementation of JMS) is used to write to that worker's queue:

```
public class ProducerService {

    private Session session;
    private MessageProducer producer;

    public ProducerService() {
        initializeSessionAndProducer()
    }

    private void initializeSessionAndProducer() { ... }

    public void sendMessage(Long id) {
        Message message = this.session.createObjectMessage(t);
        producer.send(message);
    }
}
```

Both applications are packaged as a docker image. Here's some logging output showing that the sqsd is met with a 400.

```
2016-11-16T21:37:17Z message: sent to http://localhost:80
2016-11-16T21:37:18Z http-err: 321ca22b-8137-4970-ad8a-54dbe83cc6a7 (1) 400 - 0.494
```

Here's all of the Elastic Beanstalk Configuration:

```
//  Scaling
//    Environment type: Single instance
//    Custom Availability Zones: blank
//  Instances
//    Instance type: t2.small
//    Availability Zones: Any
//  Notifications
//    Notifications: Off
//  Software Configuration
//    Environment variables: env
//    Log publication: On
//  Updates and Deployments
//    Deployment policy: All at once
//    Rolling updates are disabled
//  Worker Configuration
//    Worker queue URL https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/WORKER
//    HTTP path: /
//    MIME type: application/json
//    HTTP connections: 50
//    Visibility timeout: 1800
//  Health
//    Application health check URL: blank
//    Health reporting: Basic
//  Managed Updates
//    Managed updates are disabled
```

I've tried modifying my endpoint to receive an Object but the same error code occurs. Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the controller is configured to accept application/json when sqsd is sending what was put on the queue, a base64 encoded, serialized Long. Here's a way for that endpoint to accommodate what is on the queue:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void runMicroservice(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    if (microservice != null) {
        byte b[] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
        microservice.receiveMessage((Long) si.readObject());
    }
    else System.exit(-1);
}
```